# Hibernate annotation Cascade problem

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, cascade, constraints

I have a Java class that contains a list of another class.

```
@Entity public class Country {


private Long id;
private List<Hotel> hotels;

public void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="COUNTRY_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="COUNTRY_SEQ", sequenceName="COUNTRY_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
public Long getId() {
return id;
}

public void setHotels(List<Hotel> hotels) {
this.hotels = hotels;
}

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
    name="COUNTRY_HOTELS",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="HOTEL_ID")
)
public List<Hotel> getHotels() {
return hotels;
}

}
```

When I try to delete a Country, I get "ORA-02292: integrity constraint (HOT.fk1a1e72aaf2b226a) violated - child record found" because it can't delete a Country when its children (=Hotels) still exist.

However, it is MEANT to be like this!  I don't want to my Hotels deleted when I delete a Country.

I tried **without** any @Cascade-annotation but it failed.  I also tried with SAVE_UPDATE, still failed.
So which @Cascade-annotation do I need (or is there another solution?):

- PERSIST
- MERGE
- REMOVE
- REFRESH
- DELETE
- SAVE_UPDATE
- REPLICATE
- DELETE_ORPHAN
- LOCK
- EVICT

Bart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the hotels from the list of hotels of the country before deleting the country, in order to tell Hibernate that the hotels don't have a country anymore.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you (and justYo) are saying but here is another problem:
All our actions are done in methods that are marked as @Transactional.

Comment: My last comment was not complete: here's the full text:

All our actions are done in methods that are marked as @Transactional which means all of those statements (set hotels-list  to nuull, save, delete) will be executed after the method has completed.  So, it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: Try inspecting the SQL queries generated by Hibernate, and see if the deletes on the join table appear before the delete on the country table. Don't set the list to null, clear it, and only after delete the hotel. If it still doesn't work, try flushing the session after the call to clear and before the call to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Hibernate doesn't support `ON DELETE SET NULL` type of cascade yet. 
So you have to delete references manually first and only then delete child entity.

There is a [future request](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2707) for Hibernate to support it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use Oracle. It allows you to implement cascade delete at the database level by defining foreign key `COUNTRY_ID` with `ON DELETE CASCADE` (http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but our application should be portable so we want to minimize database-specific stuff.